# How to validate and restrict input to UITextField inside UIAlertView in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uialertview

I am using the `UIAlertView` to show the text field over a popup. But the problem I am facing is that I am not able to validate and restrict the entries in `UITextField` over a popup, i.e. I want to accept only 3 numeric values.

Here i am providing the block of code that I have implemented.

```
popup = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please enter 3 numeric values"
                                   message:@"\n\n"
                                  delegate:self
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                         otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];         

txtFld = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 50, 260, 25)];
[txtFld setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[txtFld setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
[popup addSubview:txtFld];

[popup show];

[txtFld becomeFirstResponder];
```

So can anyone help me out to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried using UITextFieldDelegate protocol? I think it should work

Comment: Thanks the69geeks. This is useful for validatiing the fields value but I want to restrict user to enter only numeric values, how can I get that.

Comment: Keep in mind that it is risky to manually add subviews to `UIAlertView` or any other view you do not control as its hierarchy is private and subject to change. If you're targeting iOS 5 and above, you can use one of the `UIAlertView` styles that supports text entry such as `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`.

Comment: Justin I didnt get you, can you please elaborate more on this. Please tell where, what and how to use it, if possible please post a block of code.

Comment: I will instead point you to the answer. The information is easily found in the [documentation for UIAlertView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html). If you need close guidance, try [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-5-sdk-uialertview-text-input-and-validation), then post a question if you have specific issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here I can see that you have not set textfield.delegate=self , please check it in your code

Answer (score 1):

It is risky to manually add subviews to `UIAlertView` or any other view you do not control as its hierarchy is private and subject to change. If you're targeting iOS 5 or above, you can use one of the `UIAlertView` styles that supports text entry and validation such as `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`. The documentation for [`UIAlertView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) provides a list of styles and [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-5-sdk-uialertview-text-input-and-validation/) explains their use in more detail.